# How can I handle six SoftwareSerial ports for six Nova SDS011 Air Quality Sensors on Arduino MEGA?

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, softwareserial

First of all, thank you in advance.

I'm trying to connect six [*Nova SDS011 Air Quality Sensor*](http://inovafitness.com/en/a/chanpinzhongxin/95.html) (sensor specifications [here](https://www-sd-nf.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/%E5%AE%98%E7%BD%91%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD/SDS011%20laser%20PM2.5%20sensor%20specification-V1.4.pdf)) to an Arduino MEGA. I'm using the [**Nova Fitness Sds dust sensors** library](https://github.com/lewapek/sds-dust-sensors-arduino-library) which relys on the **SoftwareSerial** library. As fas as I know, SoftwareSerial can handle a virtual serial port on any digital pin (with some limitations as seen on [Arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial)), but I don't know whether there is any limit on the number of ports that it can handle.

I have communicated successfully with four of them which are conected to the pins:

| RX | TX | Sensor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 12 | 1 |
| 10 | 11 | 2 |
| 51 | 50 | 3 |
| 53 | 52 | 4 |
| XX | XX | 5 |
| XX | XX | 6 |

The two sensors left (5 and 6) have been tested on the Arduino remaining free pins, but it couldn't listen to the ports. I checked if all sensors worked propperly separatedly, and they do, so I can dischart that the problem is related with a faulty sensor. The pins for the serial ports have been declared (for each sensor) as:

```
// Sensor 1
const uint8_t rxPin1 = 13;  // Brown wire
const uint8_t txPin1 = 12;  // Violet wire
SoftwareSerial sensor1(rxPin1, txPin1);
SdsDustSensor dust_sensor_1(sensor1);
```

As I have seen on Arduino Reference, I must use the `.listen()` and `.isListening()` functions in order to listen to a specific port:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("===========================================");

  // SDS sensors configuration
  dust_sensor_1.begin();
  dust_sensor_2.begin();
  dust_sensor_3.begin();
  dust_sensor_4.begin();
  dust_sensor_5.begin();
  dust_sensor_6.begin();

  sensor1.listen();
  dust_sensor_1.wakeup();
  delay(100);
  if (sensor1.isListening()) {
    dust_sensor_1.setQueryReportingMode();
    String status_mode_1 = dust_sensor_1.setQueryReportingMode().toString();
    while (!status_query.equals(status_mode_1)) {
      dust_sensor_1.setQueryReportingMode();
      status_mode_1 = dust_sensor_1.setQueryReportingMode().toString();
      Serial.print("Sensor 1 mode >> "); Serial.println(status_mode_1);
    }
    Serial.print("Sensor 1 mode >> "); Serial.println(status_mode_1);
  }
  dust_sensor_1.sleep();

  delay(1000);

  // Next sensors
}
```

The code from above is the same for each sensor, but I have condensed the whole `setup()` code in just one sensor.

If that code has worked for four sensors, it isn't strange to think that the same code should work for six too. I'm completely stuck at this point and I don't know what I should do. I will not write the `loop()` code untill the `setup()` works fine.

At last, when all problems will have been solved and the sensors will tested, I will swap the code into a state machine for a better performance. I will also change some variables that could be joined into a single variable (such as `String status_mode_1` which can be just `String status_mode`; it can be shared with all sensors).

If you happen to need the whole code, please ask for it and then i'll post it.

Comment: What pins have you tried for the remaining sensors? Unrelated, but the code would be incrementally easier to reason about if the ports/sensors were stored in an array (and I'd recommend using only a `singleNamingConvention`).

Comment: Not all pins on the Mega and Mega 2560 support change interrupts, so only the following can be used for RX: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 50, 51, 52, 53, A8 (62), A9 (63), A10 (64), A11 (65), A12 (66), A13 (67), A14 (68), A15 (69).

Comment: @DaveNewton I have tried all of the remaining digital and analog pins. Regarding the array, I hadn't thought about it and yes, I should use singleNamingConvention, sorry. Juraj, I have seen that info on Arduino Reference web, and I tried all those pins at first, and only worked (for me) 10, 11, 12, 13, 50, 51, 52 and 53, the ones I wrote on the table.

Comment: Off the top of my head can't think of anything obvious. Have you tried a simple sketch with a single sensor on one of the available pins you haven't tried? (Another reason having the ports/sensors in an array is that it's much easier to make changes like that :)

Comment: I have tried with just one sensor, but with an Arduino UNO. I'll try what you say and I'll edit this comment ASAP.

Comment: TX pin can be any pin. only RX pins must support pin interrupt

Comment: I have just tried with one sensor using random pins and the specific, as @Juraj sugested. If I use digital pins it seems it works fine, but if I use an analog pin (A8, for instance) it looks it takes some more time to do the task. The behaviour is the same with the six sensors, on analog pins it seems it takes some more time. Yesterday I also tried with all free pins for TX and RX, and it didn't work; maybe, I was declaring a variable wrong, I don't know. I had already worked with SoftwareSerial, but with less sensors. Anyway, it seems it works now and I thank all of you ;)